# Adding A Dynamic Link In Php

Tags: php, string, hyperlink, anchor

I have been using the following to add a dynamic link on a page I am writing, it works ok and appears how it should on the page but I cant help but think that I am going a bit backwards with the way its written as it looks messy. What is the correct way to write it, as if I put it all in one line it doesn't work ?..

```
echo '<a href="./customer-files/';
        echo $customerID;
        echo '/';
        echo $filename->getFilename();
        echo '">';
              echo $filename->getFilename();
    echo '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd approach it like this:

```
$safe_customer_id = htmlspecialchars(urlencode($customerID));
$safe_filename = htmlspecialchars(urlencode($filename->getFilename()));
$safe_label = htmlspecialchars($filename->getFilename());
echo "<a href=\"./customer-files/$safe_customer_id/$safe_filename\">$safe_label</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks :) , will this remove any spaces etc from the filename too ?

Comment: It won't remove them, it will replace them with URL safe alternatives … but that's a good point. It shouldn't be done on the visible filename. (Answer edited)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
echo "<a href=\"./customer-files/{$customerID}/{$filename->getFilename()}\">{$filename->getFilename()}</a>";
```

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) there is the documentation with a lot of examples of how to concatenate output.

Comment: I'd not recommend that approach, since it doesn't highlight HTML in an IDE, and may require horizontal scrolling when editing. I think lines should be shorter, where possible.

Comment: Ah, and your variables won't get expanded, since you're inside single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: I've corrected the single quotes issue. Regarding your first comment, I have not thought about IDEs. About the line length, it's just a matter of personal tastes I think. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No worries, the swap of ideas is good `:)`, +1. There used to be a recommendation for 80 characters, though with wider screens these days that is perhaps a little defunct; I work to 100. It's worth noting though that some template code doesn't allow for it (e.g. a long <a> plus its content - breaking the content into a new indent introduces unwanted space). More [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=coding+line+length) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation is your friend. Use a `.` to combine multiple string expression into one.

```
echo '<a href="./customer-files/'.$customerID.'/'.$filename->getFilename().'">'.$filename->getFilename()/'</a>';
```

Even better way would be

```
$filename = $filename -> getFilename(); //cache the filename
echo "<a href='/$customerId/$filename'>$filename</a>";
  // ^ On this echo NOTICE that variables can be DIRECTLY placed inside Double qoutes.
```

Comment: Problem with your `<a>` is that you're using single quotes for attributes; that'll not produce standards-compliant HTML, afaik.

Comment: Just looked, and apologies - you're quite right. I was quite positive HTML5 and XHTML both require speech marks rather than apostrophes for attributes, and it turns out neither of them do. Even XML! `:-o` I had no idea.

Comment: @halfer, Great, I am removing my comment then !

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this:

```
$fn = $filename->getFilename();
$link = $customerID . '/' . $fn;
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$fn.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a template layer, it is even better to break out into PHP only when you need to:

```
<a href="./customer-files/<?php
    echo $customerID . '/' . $filename->getFilename()
?>">
    <?php echo $filename->getFilename() ?>
</a>
```

This way, your IDE will correctly highlight your HTML as well as your PHP. I've also ensured that all PHP is in single-line blobs, which is the best approach for templates (lengthy statements should be banished to a controller/script).